# Transition with a view with SwiftUI without animating the entire view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using SwiftUI, I have a view that includes a slider that I'm using a transition to slide in from the bottom.  All works well, until the slider is moved quickly back and forth. With that, the text field is being animated, and will show "..." when changing from 1 to two digits.

Here is my test code showing this:

```
struct TestSliderView: View {
    @State private var val: Double = 0
    @State private var showSlider: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showSlider.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Slider")
            }
            Spacer()

            if showSlider {
                JustTheSlider(val: $val)
                    .padding()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.4))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct JustTheSlider: View {
    @Binding var val: Double
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Slider")
                .font(.title)
            HStack {
                Text("Value: ")
                    .frame(minWidth: 80, alignment: .leading)
                Slider(value: $val, in: 0...30, step: 1)
                Text("\(Int(val))")
                    .frame(minWidth: 20, alignment: .trailing)
                    .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One way around this would be to remove the `.animation(.linear(duration: 0.4))` line and wrap the button action with an animation like so:

```
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.4)) {
                    self.showSlider.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Show Slider")
            }
```

This stops the text from animating, but then the view only slides out, and just pops in without any slide animation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need animate the state variable, not the View.

```
 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation{
                self.showSlider.toggle()}

        }) {
            Text("Show Slider")
        }
        Spacer()

        if showSlider {
            JustTheSlider(val: $val)
                .padding()
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))

        }
    }
}
```

As the last line shown.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this does solve the problem with the text animating, this causes the text itself to pop in immediately on its own, and not slide in with the rest of the view.

Comment: Yes, but if you do that, then only the removal of the view is animated (slides out), where my goal is to have JustTheSlider slide both in and out.

Comment: Tried it on every simulator, still didn't slide out...until I tried it on an actual device, and on there, it works correctly. While I wish the simulator worked as expected, I'm glad to see that the code does what it should. Thank you!